# primefaces blockui does not hide

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog that is shown for user input.
This dialog has some validations and when the validation fails the blockui goes away.

This works well on my laptop with everything on it.
But when I deploy the war file onto the remote server and test it my blockui does not "unblock" after validation error. I get my growl message stating which field is wrong and the growl goes away but the blockui keeps blocking my dialog. Not allowing the user to correct the input.

```
                <p:commandButton id="bttAddUser" value="Submit" update=":contentView:lstUsers :growl"  oncomplete="handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, 'newUserDialog','newUserForm');" actionListener="#{userController.create}">
                    <p:blockUI id="addBlockUI" trigger="bttAddUser" block="newUserGrid"></p:blockUI>
                </p:commandButton>
```

Both systems, my laptop and remote server have glassfish 3.1.2.2. I was trying to figure out if there is a way of doing this and force the unblock of the ui.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

So it seems that is not a network problem but something else:
I'm actually getting an error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

My dialog:

```
    <h:form id="newUserForm">
        <p:panelGrid id="newUserGrid" columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Email : " ></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText value="#{userController.newUser.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please the email of the user" validatorMessage="Email is invalid" >
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
            </p:inputText>

            <h:outputText value="Name : " ></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText value="#{userController.newUser.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please the name of the user" ></p:inputText>

            <h:outputText value="Role"></h:outputText>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="newUserRole" required="true" value="#{userController.newUser.roleid}" requiredMessage="A role must be chosen">
                <f:selectItems value="#{userController.listRoles}" var="_role" itemValue="#{_role}" itemLabel="#{_role.roleid}"></f:selectItems>
                <f:converter converterId="misc.util.RoleConverter"></f:converter>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputText value="TimeZone"></h:outputText>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="newUserTz" required="true" value="#{userController.newUser.tzone}" requiredMessage="TimeZone must be specified">
                <f:selectItems value="#{userController.listTimeZone}" var="_tz" itemValue="#{_tz}" itemLabel="#{_tz}">  </f:selectItems>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>
            <p:password value="#{userController.newUser.password}" required="true"  requiredMessage="Define a password"></p:password>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="bttAddUser" value="Submit" update=":contentView:lstUsers :growl"  oncomplete="handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, 'newUserDialog','newUserForm');" actionListener="#{userController.create}">
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset"></p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>
            <p:blockUI id="addBlockUI" trigger="bttAddUser" block="newUserGrid" widgetVar="blockUI"></p:blockUI>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

I get the error on Solaris but not in Windows. Both have glassfish 3.1.2.2 build 5.

Comment: This is interesting. I think that blockUI is designed to return after a request initiated by or involving its `trigger` component returns a (successful?) response. You should look in your browser's developer console to observe the http traffic btw browser and server (on both your localhost and remote host).

Comment: Thank for the tip, I've been checking and checking but so far nothing good. In both environments I get the same post and get, the only difference if the full exchange takes twice as long on remote server than on my local computer. I think it might have to do with timing or the blockui is on the wrong place.
I guess that I'll try to implement validation in the bean and hide from there if it fails :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed this.

I had two primefaces jars in my WebApp:

One in domain/lib and the other one under WEB-INF/lib.

It seems that when using some functions of primefaces, it would return more than it should.

Post in [Primefaces Forums](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24368)